# Sending large data packet to server

Tags: android, file-upload, large-files, gsm

Having a design discussion with some co-workers about our app.  Looking for the best way to transfer large data files on a, say, weekly basis from a phone to a remote server.  Server will
be in the DMZ and phone will either be in WiFi mode or GSM.  Some of the files will be 100Mb can even get up to 400Mb.  Just not sure of the best way to approach this in my Android code.  I was looking at
MTOM or even just pure FTP.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Development questions are off-topic, a mod will likely migrate this to StackOverflow.

Comment: By packet, I assume you mean file or 'package' correct? Where is the file/package originating, a client machine or another server on your network?

Comment: Were saving the data to file, which can exceed 8K data per sec.  The device is communicating to phone via Bluettooth using SPP and we are saving the raw data, then transmit that file saved over phone to our own central server.  Looking for best way to transmit over phone and guarantee file gets to server uncorrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have investiagated about the use of MTOM under Android but I found nothing. I don't know whether there's any implementation working with Android yet.

But this is something you can do [by FTP](http://hoang17.com/posts/android/android-how-to-upload-a-file-via-ftp), which would be a good choice I think. And you could check the integrity of the file using a checksum (calculated on both sides and then compared).

Using 3G for huge files is likely to take long and to be expensive, so to me the best is to use WiFi. You can detect whether your device is connected thru WiFi [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185975/how-to-run-my-application-when-phone-is-charging-or-connected-through-wifi/7186048#7186048).

Comment: Unfortunately we can't use WiFi as this will be deployed to users who are mostly poor and not tech savvy.  We have to use the 3/4G connection so most likely it looks like we are going to use FTP.  Thanks for your input!  Cheers.